# Creating user accounts/variables that can be read/written/validated from a file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a homework task for C# that requires reading/writing user emails, passwords, addresses to text files (yes, I know storing user info in plaintext isn't safe; it's just for the hw task). The user information will be created when they register with an email, password, and name and an address will be added later. The email and password will be used to sign in, too, so it needs to be able to validate with info in the text file.

I have some existing variables `email` and `password` from when a user initially registers, but I'm unsure of how to store these. I was thinking something where each user is assigned a number (or like `User1`, `User2`, etc) and incrementing the user number each time someone new registers.

I have some basic `FileStream` code from when I was playing around with the methods, but I'm not sure how to further implement it.

```
        static void WriteFile(string Filename, string TextInput)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            if (fs.CanWrite)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextInput);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            fs.Flush(); 
            fs.Close(); 
        }

        static void ReadFile(string Filename)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            int bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesread));

            fs.Close();
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "UserDatabase.txt");
        string Filename = path;
        WriteFile(Filename);
        ReadFile(Filename);
        Console.Read();
```

I had been thinking that the `TextInput` could be the user information, but I'm unsure of how to structure it, like if I use lists or something else? These user accounts will also store further information (the overall task is like creating a mini eBay), but I'm just looking to understand/see the basic structure of a user for now.

Still learning, so not sure if I've missed something obvious. Thanks

Comment: fwiw, plain-text passwords is one of only about three things that's too sensitive to do wrong even for things like learning/proof_of_concept/homework, and you can show this to your prof if you want to suggest a new assignment. But to actually address this issue, CSV or JSON data are popular formats you could use.

Comment: yeah, I know plaintext is the worst for passwords. we're not really even allows to hash it, because they want to see that the data is being written properly into the file.  is there a good tutorial anywhere fir json databases? I don't think it explicitly has to be a .txt file, just that it can be opened and read outside of the program